# fs.exists method doesnt exist anymore in node.js

Tags: node.js

Im using node v0.6.12

This is my code:

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.exists(".", function() {
    console.log("Whatever);
});
```

I get this output:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'exists'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dbugger/Projects/nodetest/test.js:3:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:32)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:41)
```

Has "exists" been deprecated? What can I use then?

Comment: Which version of node did you test? Include the result of `console.log(process.version);` -- In 0.8.14, [`fs.exists`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) exists. but I also remember that in 0.6.16 it was named `path.exists`.

Comment: Im using v0.6.12: Ive tried fs.path.exists, but it doesnt work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `path.exists()` but it's deprecated in the latest version of node.  The preferred api is `fs.exists()` these days, so you'll need to be prepared to switch at some point.

```
$ node --version
v0.8.3

$ node
> require('fs').exists
[Function]
> require('path').exists
[Function: deprecated]
```

The relevant docs:

- http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.12/api/all.html
- http://nodejs.org/api/all.html

Answer (score 2):

What is your node version? I get the same result on my machine (v0.6.14). I think the `exists()` method has been moved from the `path` module to the `fs` module recently. Try `path.exists()`

Comment: Im using v0.6.12. Ive tried "fs.path.exists" and that doesnt work either

Comment: Not `fs.path.exists`. path is a separate module. `var path = require('path'); path.exists('.', function (...`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, upgrading to the latest version of node (0.8.12) solved the issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem in Raspberry Pi. Because if we just run

```
  sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
```

this wont install latest version of NodeJs. In order to install newest version of NodeJs run this command

```
  # Note the new setup script name for Node.js v0.10
  curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.10 | sudo bash -

  # Then install with:
  sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Don't try to install  Node.js v0.12 on Raspberry Pi. There is an unsolved issue is still there (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24059/node-js-v0-11-14-exits-with-illegal-instruction)

If above method doesn't work, follow this one  https://learn.adafruit.com/node-embedded-development/installing-node-dot-js