# Why there is no function fs.exists from Node.js on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I am migrating Node.js code from windows to Ubuntu 12.04, an error happens when running the code saying 'fs' has no method 'exists'. the code is like

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.exists ...
```

I checked the doc from nodejs.org and did not found any instruction of API difference on different platforms. Did I missing anything of configuring Node.js on Ubuntu?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137277/fs-exists-method-doesnt-exist-anymore-in-node-js

Comment: Ubuntu 12 seems to ship with an ancient Node (which probably has `path.exists()`), try installing a more recent version manually (or use [this tutorial](http://slopjong.de/2012/10/31/how-to-install-the-latest-nodejs-in-ubuntu/))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fs.exists` was added in node 0.7.1. So if you are using node before that you cannot use that function. Check your node version using `node -v` to confirm this.

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed that apt-get install nodejs on Ubuntu server only installs 0.6 version.